# Negative Oscillating Signal with Op-Amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, oscillation, wien-bridge, sinusoidal

I am trying to design a Wein Bridge oscillator that oscillates with frequency 1.5 kHz using LM741 Op-Amp. I simulate it in LT-Spice and obtained sinusoidal oscillation going both positive and negative. But when I fabricated it in perf-board, I am obtaining sinusoidal oscillation in the negative regime only. I would be really glad if someone could tell me if I am missing something on this.
[image: Circuit I used to simulate for oscillator]

The output that I obtained from simulation is like below:

[image: Simulation Output]

Output obtained after soldering the circuit in perf-board is below(You can see that oscillation is in negative with upper peak at -360 mV and lower peak at -1.21 V(with Vpp of 850 mVpp):

[image]

Comment: The LM741 datasheet shows the suggested supply voltage as +/- 15 V - at that voltage it can't get the output witihin 2 volts of the supply.  You area very lucky to get anything out of it with a +/- 3.3 V supply.

Comment: @Peter Bennett Indeed the datasheet suggests supply voltage of +/-15 V but i need to use it at using power supply of +/- 3.3 V. I used it to simulate and i got the result but I couldn't replicate the same thing in perf-board.

Comment: If you need to use an op-amp with a +/-3.3 V supply, look for one specified to operate with that voltage.  The LM741 is an ancient device - there are many modern op-amps that will work much better than the LM741 at low voltages.

Comment: Add an output capacitor and you will have a symmetrical waveform around zero.